# Batch to copy word to clipboard in windows xp

Tags: batch

I am trying to copy a word thaT I put in the batch to the clipboard in wondows xp like I did in windows 10 but the same batch file won't work and keeps saying unrecognized command clip on the windows xp machine and the windows 10 machine works perfectly.

This is what I have so far and want to have it do the same stuff in windows xp if possible so nobody can see the password being entered.

Thanks in advance.

```
if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED set IS_MINIMIZED=1 && start "" /min "%~dpnx0" %* && exit

@echo off


echo|set /p=MyPassWord|clip

echo.

cls
ping localhost -n 60 >nul

echo|<nul set /p="" | clip
dir >nul | clip 
cd %cd% | clip
pushd %cd% | clip
cd >nul | clip
echo.
exit
```

Comment: Probably the clip command is not available in Windows XP

Answer (score 1):

[The clip.exe command did not exist with Windows XP](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/copy-and-paste-from-windows-xp-pros-command-prompt-straight-to-the-clipboard/).
The first release of it came shortly after with Windows Server 2003.

No offense but I really can't figure out what you are trying to do here.  It all seems like a bad solution and the worst possible "password" control but you do you.

What exactly are all of the commands being piped to clip supposed to do?

For instance:

- `dir >nul | clip`
- `cd >nul | clip`

I read: "take standard out and redirect it to NUL.  If there is an error (stderr), pipe it to the clipboard".  In these two cases.  Essentially.. do nothing.

Am I reading this wrong?

At least you know you can't use the command in XP unless you get it from somewhere else.

Comment: For those I didn't write them and got them from the web.  That clears the password from the clipboard.   I am trying to make a batch file that I can put the password in for a press that we have and since we have 15 of them ranging from xp to win 10 I need it to work on all of them.  The  password locks it so operators can't make unsafe changes to program and you need to type the password in to unlock it to make changes and they like to watch.  So I want it to put the password on the clipboard and clear screen and minimize the cmd window and c=start a timer to clear the clipboard after so long

Comment: I know it doesn't fix your XP issue but there is no need to run all of the commands to wipe the clipboard.  If you are simply trying to make the password go away, a single `echo.|clip` will put a single carriage return in there (or any one of the commands I mention above).  [You might need to get the clip.exe utility from a different source](https://www.johnsphones.com/windows/copy-and-paste-from-windows-xp-pros-command-prompt-straight-to-the-clipboard) and copy it onto your xp boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the code worked  fine it was actually windows xp itself.  I needed to go to the web and find it on my own.

I had to paste the clip.exe in 2 folders for 32 bit or 1 folder for 64 bit ad then it worked like a charm.

Thanks to Señor CMasMas for helping and pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I am glad you found the file yourself.  That was what i hoped for. :)  The next person will also need to find it on their own.  I am removing your link before the whole post gets pulled down by moderators for distributing Windows files.  Yes.. they will indeed do that.  Sorry to edit it.